Error on boot Kernel panic-not syncing:
I recently upgraded my Ubuntu version from 20.04 to 22.04. Since the upgrade, I have been encountering a kernel panic error:
"Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)"
This error occurs when I attempt to boot using the new kernel version 5.4.0.190-generic. However, I am able to log in using the older kernel version 5.4.0.169-generic.
Could you please assist me in resolving this issue so that I can successfully boot using the newer kernel version?

Ubuntu 22.04 should be using a 5.15 something kernel if that is the stack you are using. Here is the kernel my Ubuntu 22.04 is using 5.15.0-117-generic

A successful release-upgrade to 22.04 should install a 5.15-series kernel, so mucking about with 5.4-series seems curious. Are you sure that your release-upgrade completed without errors, including installing a 5.15-series kernel?

The error Kernel panic-not syncing can be solved by one of the following:

1. Boot with recovery mood or live session, clean any files in these directories /dev /proc /run /sys, and reboot to the normal state. the command used in recovery mood:
`rm -rf /dev/* /proc/* /run/* /sys/*`

the command used in the live session:
sudo mount /dev/sdxz /mnt/Ubuntu #replace xz with the appropriate letter and number for Ubuntu hard disk and partition 
sudo rm -rf /mnt/Ubuntu/dev/* /mnt/Ubuntu/proc/* /mnt/Ubuntu/run/* /mnt/Ubuntu/sys/*


2. Boot with recovery mode or live session, check and repair the filesystem of the Ubuntu partition. the command used in recovery mood:
fsck -f /

the command used in the live session:
sudo fsck -f /dev/sdxz #replace xz with the appropriate letter and number for Ubuntu hard disk and partition 

repeat the fsck command if there are errors, and reboot to the normal state. also, you can do this in the live session by the disks utility:


3. Boot with recovery mode or live session, and generate the initrd file. to create the initrd file for the latest installed image:
update-initramfs -u

to generate the initrd file for one of the installed images as an example:
update-initramfs -c -k 6.8.0-38-generic #replace 6.8.0-38-generic with the appropriate image

4. Reboot with the live session to chroot the system and reinstall required packages, or generate the initrd file:
mkdir ~/test 
sudo mount /dev/sdxz ~/test  #replace xz with the appropriate letter and number for Ubuntu hard disk and partition  
sudo mount --bind /dev ~/test/dev
sudo mount --bind /run ~/test/run
sudo chroot ~/test
mount none -t proc /proc
mount none -t sysfs /sys
mount none -t devpts /dev/pts
export HOME=/root
export LC_ALL=C
ln -fs /etc/machine-id /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl 
ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl  
apt update
apt-get -y upgrade
apt-get install -y ubuntu-standard zstd initramfs-tools
apt-get reinstall -y linux-generic
apt-get reinstall -y linux-image-6.8.0-38-generic #replace 6.8.0-38-generic with the appropriate image
update-initramfs -u
truncate -s 0 /etc/machine-id
rm /sbin/initctl
dpkg-divert --rename --remove /sbin/initctl
apt-get clean
rm -rf /tmp/* ~/.bash_history
umount /proc
umount /sys
umount /dev/pts
export HISTSIZE=0
exit
sudo umount ~/test/dev
sudo umount ~/test/run

Reboot to the normal state

5. Reboot with the live session, install boot-repair, select advanced options, from grub options select purge the kernels then reinstall the latest kernel.

after the process completed, reboot to the normal state.

Not an answer. A Ubuntu 22.04 uses a 5.15 kernel.

@DavidDE I update the answer.
